# Why JBoss DefaultDS is required

Tags: datasource, jboss5.x

While I was deploying my application in JBoss5.1.0.GA, I have removed the hsqldb-ds from the deploy folder and I had application specific ds file,then I have faced the issues like.

- The SLSB's are not registered in the Global JNDI
- EJBTimerService is not deployed and so on

So, is this mandatory to keep hsqldb-ds? What are utilities in JBoss using the DefaultDS ? Can I configure those utilities/services to use different data source?

Need your advice and knowledge , thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Things like the EJBTimerService use a database, and out of the box that is hsqldb-ds. You can replace this with another equally-named datasource (ie also named `DefaultDS`) configured for another datasource such as Oracle/MySQL/etc.

You can find the components that make use of `DefaultDS` by running the following command from your server folder:

```
grep DefaultDS -R *
```